# how to apply scrolling an page control on uiview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, paging

I have to scroll 3 `UIViews` using nib with paging in iPhone?

I have 3 view and there are different things on all the views. 
2 views have a able view and one have some form. so how can i scroll then with paging?

Comment: Read the UIScrollView documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good example on how to use a scroll view with paging enabled, it shows both how to use a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs for UIScrollView, and take a look at the `pagingEnabled` property: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

You can adapt Apple's PageControl sample project to suit your needs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795

Answer (score 0):

it might help you..

[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x,y) animated:NO];